# Docker build vsts 2017

Tags: c#

I created a default web API project on .Net core (2.2)(VSTS 2017) added docker support to it(windows). When I hit docker.run it compiles deploy and run the container for me and browser launches with valueController but when I try to use docker build command from CLI it errors out.

```
docker build -f  webapplication8/Dockerfile . -t app/web (docker command was 
run from solution folder context
build context to Docker daemon  18.94kB
Step 1/16 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 
AS base
---> bbd2c681af8e
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> 364a281312b0
Step 3/16 : EXPOSE 80
---> Using cache
---> b592461b38b7
Step 4/16 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
---> 89ff00e52591
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
---> Using cache
---> ec5284386fbc
Step 6/16 : COPY ["WebApplication8/WebApplication8.csproj", 
"WebApplication8/"]
---> 66df31f4798b
Step 7/16 : RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication8/WebApplication8.csproj"
---> Running in a019205ce3e5
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable 
to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. 
[C:\src\WebApplication8\WebApplication8.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   No 
such host is known [C:\src\WebApplication8\WebApplication8.csproj]
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore 
"WebApplication8/WebApplication8.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1

C:\Users\test\source\repos\WebApplication8>
```

My Docker version is

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           19.03.1
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.12.5
Git commit:        74b1e89
Built:             Thu Jul 25 21:17:08 2019
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          19.03.1
API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version:       go1.12.5
Git commit:       74b1e89
Built:            Thu Jul 25 21:25:07 2019
OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
Experimental:     false
```